# How do I configure Apache to not log certain cookies?

Tags: apache

I have Apache running as a proxy and I want to log the cookie string as part of the requests that come through the proxy, but I there are certain cookies I want to exclude since they contain sensitive info.

I know that Apache mod_log_config allows logging the whole cookie string with:

```
  %{Cookie}i
```

And I can log one particular cookie with:

```
  %{Foobar}C
```

But I want to log everything *except* certain cookies if they exist. One possible tactic I tried was to use SetEnvIf combined with %{FOO}e, which prints an environment variable, so something like:

```
  SetEnvIf = Cookie "(.*?)(Foobar=([^\s;]*;? ?))?(.*)" FILTERED_COOKIES=$1$4
```

and

```
  %{FILTERED_COOKIES}e
```

This works well if Foobar exists in the cookie string, but if Foobar doesn't exist, if just logs a "-", so I don't get all the other cookies.

It's possible that my regex might be poor, but it seems to work in the matching case, but Apache doesn't seem to handle it right in the non-matching case.

Short of writing a custom Apache mod, is there a way to exclude cookies from being logged?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to have multiple log formats. In your main config file:

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "(.*?)(Foobar=([^\s;]*;? ?))?(.*)" FILTERED_COOKIES=$1$4
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{Cookie}i" common
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{FILTERED_COOKIES}e" filtered
```

Then in your VirtualHost, add something like this:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log filtered env=FILTERED_COOKIES
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!FILTERED_COOKIES
```